# Language change to English

Tags: steam, dota-2

My Steam installation is in Danish, which is no problem.
But my DOTA 2 installation is in Danish.

**How can I change the language from Danish (or any other language) to English in DOTA 2?**

It is so annoying, to read spell discriptions and similar in Danish - it looses that coolness, and worst off all, some discriptions are way off when compared.

I cant find the setting for this in DOTA 2.

Comment: I think this is not possible because valve just takes your native language of steam. Thats why I changed my steam native to English aswell to not have to keep playing games in Dutch.

Comment: So in order to change the language to English in DOTA 2 I have to change the Steam language to English?

Comment: I think so but then again I don't know for sure since my Steam language is English so Dota2 is in English aswell.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can either

- Change the language of steam in english
- Force the game to start in English: Right click on the game in your steam library > Properties > Tab "general" > set launch option > type: `-language "English"`
- [See steam support on language settings](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8487-WSCN-4121), section "Changing the language of individual games
  "

Comment: I tested the `-language` option and it works.

Comment: Note that if using the language tab from the game's Steam properties, "English" will use your Steam language rather than overriding it.

Comment: -language "Russian"  works aswel

Answer (score 3):

No need for launch options if you want **all** your games to be in English.

Mine was on Dutch. You should look for the UI elements I mention in your local language.

Right click the steam icon in the notification bar, click *Settings*. Go to *Interface*. That's the tab just above *Downloads*. The top option is "*Select the language you wish Steam to use (requires Steam to restart)*" and select **English**. When you press *OK*, Steam will prompt to restart, do that.

This changed Dota2 to English the next time I started it, *without doing **anything specific** for Dota2*.